# How to use native fingerprint scanner UI in android devices?

Tags: android, kotlin, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

**Requirement : How to use native fingerprint scanner UI for onscreen sensor android devices (like Samsung s10 plus).**

Working flow of fingerprint authentication is understandable. But is there any method or libraries available for obtaining native fingerprint scanner UI ?

Comment: @RahulKhurana i'm aware about the code and working flow. Question is about native UI for different devices.. Some with separate scanner and some with onscreen scanner.

Comment: As there are multiple device manufacturers which customize UI on the OS level. There is no official API by google to achieve  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to create a custom UI and replace it so that it'll be same UI for all devices

```
public class MyFingerPrintDialog extends BottomSheetDialog implements 
View.OnClickListener {

private Context context;

private Button btnCancel;
private TextView itemTitle;

private BiometricCallback biometricCallback;

public MyFingerPrintDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    setDialogView();
}

public MyFingerPrintDialog(@NonNull Context context, BiometricCallback biometricCallback) {
    super(context, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    this.biometricCallback = biometricCallback;
    setDialogView();
}

public MyFingerPrintDialog(@NonNull Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
}

protected MyFingerPrintDialog(@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
    super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
}

private void setDialogView() {
    View bottomSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_bottom_sheet, null);
    setContentView(bottomSheetView);

    btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    itemTitle = findViewById(R.id.item_title);
}
```

BiometricCallback

```
public interface BiometricCallback {

void onAuthenticationFailed();

void onAuthenticationCancelled();

void onAuthenticationSuccessful();
}
```